# Jenkins - prevent a pipeline/job from being triggered by multiple upstream projects -restrict one build to one upstream project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, build-numbers

I searched a lot online but did not find an answer to this.

We have two projects **A** and **B**, which trigger a common project **C** as it's pipeline step.
Now if A has triggered C (common project), and B also triggers C at around the same time, only one build of C is run and the result is consumed by both A and B. The build status in C shows "*Started by upstream project A*" and "*Started by upstream project B*" both.

How do I make project C first complete the build triggered by A and then start a new build for the trigger by B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using the [lockable resource plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/) in Jenkins.
So my Jenkinsfile for projects A and B look like this

```
pipeline {
agent { ... }

stages {
    stage('Invoke project C') {
        steps {
            lock('project-c-lock') {
                script {
                    ...
                    ...
                }
            }      
        }
    }

}
```

Thus this step is executed only once and synchronization takes place. It's important to have the same lock resource name.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have enabled `Do not allow concurrent builds`, unless Jenkins sees the run as a unique run it will not queue additional Jobs, Jenkins will think you are trying to run the same Job multiple times. In order to trick Jenkins you need to change a parameter each time you trigger the Job, If you use the same parameters it will think it's the same Job. So introduce a new Parameter in the target JOb (Job C) and maybe pass some random value to that which will make it unique.

In the target Job C

```
string(name: 'UniqueString', defaultValue: 'o', description: 'something')
```

In the Triggering Job A and B. Pass some random value, I'm passing

```
def randomValue = "${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_ID}"
build wait: false, job: 'otherjob', parameters: [ string(name: 'UniqueString',value: "$randomValue") 
                    ...
           ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This happened even when i had not enabled concurrent builds on project C. Finally what worked is using locks.